# Google Sign-in not working in new Huawei devices: "There was a problem communicating with google servers"

Tags: google-account, google, huawei

Between the 11th and the 13th of September 2020 something has changed around the method used to log into Google accounts from new Huawei devices after installing Google Mobile Services (GMS).

Before, the method involved installing GMS-related apps and signing into the relevant Google accounts using browser sign-in (a legacy sign-in method kept for old android versions). However, it seems like just after Huawei announced Harmony OS, that backdoor was closed.

**Is there any way to sign into Google accounts for GMS from a new Huawei device (such as a P40 pro)?**

> **Disclaimer 1:** I hope no one gets offended by this question being asked... I think that from a consumer perspective it is legit to try to find solutions to the side effects of what effectively seems to be a trade war.
>
> At the end of the day, there are hundreds of thousands of users
> affected by this situation and they are not the ones to blame for any conflict between governments and/or companies.

> **Disclaimer 2:** The consequences of the ban get to an absurd level, is not just not having Google Play Store, but for example not being able to log into your Google account from your browser to sync passwords, history and bookmarks... Hope this helps people not experiencing the ban understanding the extent of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your phone identification to any other smartphone brand and to change IMEI codes as well but let me tell you that it's against the law and I do not encourage it.

But in your place, I will simply sell it on any online platform and buy another smartphone with not a banned brand such as Samsung or Nokia.

Comment: Guessing this is only possible with a rooted phone, right?

Comment: Changing phone would mean either doubling the budget or halving the specs... Not ideal

Comment: @JesusIniesta Correct, but if it doesn't work for what you need, then you don't have the right phone. Huawei got rid of unlocking bootloaders years ago, so rooting is rarely an option unless a special, device specific exploit is found. Unfortunately, Huawei has largely been blacklisted in the US government and many US based service providers, so if it doesn't do what you need it to you, might be better to cut your losses and move on to a different device, and at that level of device there are a ton of competitive devices.

Comment: If you're concerned about budget, you could try Samsung Halaxy A01, it has 2GB ram, 16GB storage and is worth $100. You could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just that. Google will eventually close every door you  open. It's not some startup company you dealing with.  If you manage to find a way, small group of people will make use of this opportunity. After that,  many users will not be able to install GMS. And you are back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

With root, you can fake your device as something else using [MagiskHide Props Config](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/MagiskHidePropsConf) and bypass this.